# my CSS file is not linking to my HTML file even when they are in the same folder

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Daniel Erhabor | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="JS_CSS_HTML_HW_css_file.css" type="text/css" >
</head>



<body>

    <div id = "headerblock">
        <h1>
        Daniel Erhabor Ph.D
        </h1>
    </div>


    <ul>
    <li> <a href="  JS_CSS_HTML_HW_home_page.html "> Home </a>
    <li> <a href=" JS_CSS_HTML_HW_courses_page.html"> Course </a>
    <li> <a href=" JS_CSS_HTML_HW_projects_page.html"> Projects </a>
    <li> <a href=" JS_CSS_HTML_HW_hobbies_page.html"> Hobbies </a>
    <li> <a href=" JS_CSS_HTML_HW_friends_page.html"> Friends </a>
    </ul>

</body>


</html>
```

This is my HTML page that is supposed to link with JS_CSS_HTML_HW_css_file.css that is in the SAME folder. I don't know why when I open developer tools and I try to view sources for the CSS file it's empty. I don't understand.

Here is my JS_CSS_HTML_HW_css_file.css

```
#headerblock h1{
background: #BEBEBE
}
```

All this is supposed to do is to make the header have a grey background. Why isn't it working?

Comment: Try removing the spaces in your markup. ‘<div id="headerblock">’

Answer (score 1):

1) You are missing a semi colon in your css:

```
#headerblock h1{
    background: #BEBEBE;
}
```

2) If the page is not loading you should see the file not found message in the developer console when you load the page.

Comment: I think my sublime text was buggy so I dragged the file to notepad and there was no code there. I wrote the code in notepad and now it works in sublime text. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The code is perfectly alright works.

I believe you must try changing the file name and removing the underscore JS_CSS_HTML_HW_css_file.css to a simpler stlylehtml.css

Also add ; after #BEBEBE

This woudld work.

Cheers.

Comment: I think my sublime text was buggy so I dragged the file to notepad and there was no code there. I wrote the code in notepad and now it works in sublime text. Very strange behaviour. I thought the semi-colon was the problem so I removed it. But there should be a semi colon. Thanks.